# Using one grep for two result at a time

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I have this file

```
something1
something2 username": "John" something3
something4
....
something5 salaryunit="dollar" something6
something7
```

I want to get this result

```
John dollar
```

or

```
username": "John" salaryunit="dollar"
```

and I have tried

```
grep -oP 'username":".*?"\|salaryunit=".*?"' file
```

but it gets error.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a version of `grep` (such as GNU `grep`) with support for PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions) enabled by the `-P` option and support for the `-o` option to print only what's matched — neither of which is mandated by POSIX — then you need to drop the backslash before the pipe and add a space before the second double quote in the command in the question.

Given the data file:

```
something1
something2 username": "John" something3
something4
....
something5 salaryunit="dollar" something6
something7
username": "John" salaryunit="dollar"
```

running the command shown produces the output shown:

```
$ grep -oP 'username": ".*?"|salaryunit=".*?"' file
username": "John"
salaryunit="dollar"
username": "John"
salaryunit="dollar"
$
```

Note that when the pattern matches twice on a single line of input (the last in the sample data), the `-o` option outputs two separate matches on two separate lines.  When the matching input is on two separate lines, of course, the output is also on two separate lines.

If you demand 'output on a single line', you need to specify what you want as output for the augmented file, or for a variant of the file with twenty matches spread through the file.  If you want them in pairs, what should happen if there is no `salaryunit` between two `username` entries, or no `username` between two `salaryunit` entries?  Etc.

If you are confident that the entries always appear in pairs, and always in the sequence `username` then `salaryunit`, then a simple way of getting pairs of lines combined into single lines is:

```
$ grep -oP 'username": ".*?"|salaryunit=".*?"' file | paste -d ' ' - -
username": "John" salaryunit="dollar"
username": "John" salaryunit="dollar"
$
```

The `- -` notation to `paste` means 'read one line from standard input then a second and print the combination as a single line'.  By default, the lines are separated by tabs; using `-d ' '` means they're separated by a single space instead.  Using a longer delimiter doesn't work; the first character is used to separate the first two fields, the second character in the string separates the second and third fields, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan ,it goes with pairs ,i have many files and each files has `username` and `salaryunit` ,can you help me get them in one line result

Comment: You have to define all the issues outlined in my last paragraph before I can sensibly help with getting the results onto a single line — plus the questions (1) 'will `username` always appear before `salaryunit`?', and (2) 'will each file contain only one entry for each keyword?'  Please edit the question to add the extra information — do not add it as comments here.

Comment: yes,Jonathan ,that is for sure ,`username` always before 'salaryunit' and each file contain only one entry for each keyword